# C#: How to #define within an #if?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a certain method that runs as a background task and does some fancy things. It is SLOW, because of the Thread.Sleep(500);. It doesn't need to do things faster, and it changes the behaviour of my application very subtle. Enter problem: When running my unit and component tests, I need to have the task run as it is supposed to be, for, like say 95 percent of my test cases. But of course I want to test the method itself. The subtle changes may arise after let's say half an hour or so. Not a good idea for a test suite. What I need is a way to speed things up for exactly this very test case.

Because #define isn't allowed to appear within code, the only way I see is to write an extra test case file for this test? I'd love something like this:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Test_GetThisThingAndRunIt()
{
    // ...
    #if DEBUG
    #define CRV_TEST
    // run the test
    #undef CRV_TEST
    #endif
}
```

etc. and then, in the class to test, do something like

```
#if CRV_TEST
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
#else
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
#endif
```

How to? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not how preprocessor directives work. It seems to me that the class you're testing should allow the sleep duration to be passed into it via a parameter or property somewhere. (Then you can use the appropriate value on a per-test basis.)

Comment: The C# preprocessor does not work that way. Either also define `CRV_TEST` as part of your debug build, or use the `DEBUG` to declare a separate constant that you feed to the `Sleep` unconditionally or (best of all) refactor and rewrite until your tests are in no way, shape or form dependent on exact or approximate running times anymore, as that's a recipe for maintenance headaches. If all else fails, you can typically smuggle in setting an event somewhere and checking for it, even if it's used for nothing more than allowing a test to work.

Comment: @TanveerBadar C# allows [Preprocessor Directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/)

Comment: Probably the best would be to change the `RunTheTest()` method to include an argument that specifies the sleep time: `RunTheTest(TimeSpan sleepTime)`, and then `#if DEBUG RunTheTest(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));` This way anything that runs the test can set the appropriate sleep time.